# Delete request by Restlet with payload

Tags: java, rest, http, restlet, http-method

Does Restlet API support to incorporate and trigger the DELETE http request with the payload (If support which version of restlet api). According to RFC7231, All http methods support the payload. If possible can post segment of code for this scenario if you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Restlet supports HTTP DELETE method.

For example you can do something like:

```
public interface EntityResource {

  @ApiOperation(value = "Get entity", tags = "entity")
  @Get
  Representation getEntity();

  @ApiOperation(value = "Update entity", tags = "entity")
  @Put
  Representation updateEntity(Representation entity);

  @ApiOperation(value = "Delete entity", tags = "entity")
  @Delete
  void deleteEntity(Representation entity);

}
```